# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.transaction.manager.properties.TransacationManagerProperties' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

TransactionManagerApplication

```
package com.example.transaction.manager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

import com.comvia.transaction.manager.properties.TransacationManagerProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class TransactionManagerApplication {
    @Autowired 
    private TransacationManagerProperties yamlFooProperties;

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TransactionManagerApplication.class, args);
        TransactionManagerApplication manager = new TransactionManagerApplication();
        manager.print();
    }
    public void  print() {
        System.out.println("yamlFooProperties :: "+yamlFooProperties.getPassword());
    }

}
```

TransacationManagerProperties

```
package com.example.transaction.manager.properties;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import com.comvia.transaction.manager.properties.factory.YamlPropertySourceFactory;

import lombok.Data;


@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "transaction_manager.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@Profile("development")
@Data
public class TransacationManagerProperties {

    @Value("${db.userName}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${list}")
    private List<String> list;


}
```

Getting error while starting application :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field yamlFooProperties in com.comvia.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.transaction.manager.properties.TransacationManagerProperties' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.transaction.manager.properties.TransacationManagerProperties' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove autowiring of beans from the class where you start the application because the beans are not registered unless this line of code `SpringApplication.run(<SomeClass>.class, args)` runs.

Modify in this way given below :

Updated TransactionManagerApplication class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TransactionManagerApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TransactionManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Create a sample class implementing CommandLineRunner (which is an interface and telling spring that this bean should run when present in SpringApplication. In simple words, this will execute after `SpringApplication.run(<SomeClass>.class, args)` is executed.

```
@Component
public class TransactionManagerRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired 
    private TransacationManagerProperties yamlFooProperties;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("yamlFooProperties :: "+yamlFooProperties.getPassword());
    }
}
```